# iOS specific error during SDK setup

Tags: ios, mobilepush-ios

Some users has encountered this error:

```
  Domain: MarketingCloudSDKErrorDomain Code: 4 NSLocalizedDescription: <MarketingCloudSDK+Base.m:(438)> iOS file protection is enabled and data is not available even after 5 seconds of waiting
```

What can I do about that?

Comment: If iOS Data Protection is enabled and the file system is not available the SDK will attempt to retry the configuration for up to 5 seconds to give the device time to unlock and enable the file system. If it does NOT unlock, the error is returned and the SDK cannot continue to configure.

See our troubleshooting section for more information on using the SDK and the various iOS Data Protection levels.
https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/trouble/trouble-ios-data-protection.html

Comment: See the Learning Application sample code (specifically the app delegate code) for the recommended way to handle iOS Data Protection with the SDK.
https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/blob/master/LearningApp/LearningApp/AppDelegate.swift

Comment: @JeffSylvia Thank you, I have figured out that already :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was using the latest SDK version without it's recommended implementation for iOS data protection. I haven't read docs and change-log before updating the SDK, my mistake